# I want to search string from unix file only if it is followed by another string

Tags: linux, unix, awk

For example  I have a below text file :

```
STUVWXY    
FOLLOWS    
HIM     
ABCDEFG    
FOLLOWS    
HIM    
IJKLMNO    
FOLLOWS    
HIM
```

---

Like I want to search everything that is before `HIM` like here output should be `STUVWXY, ABCDEFG, IJKLMNO` since they are following `HIM`

Comment: Didja try anything?

Comment: Except for the first line. Do you have any language preferences? Personally I would do this with awk, but Perl would also be a good candidate.

Comment: So you want to print the line that's 2 lines before HIM, not the line immediately before HIM?

Comment: I think that the word `FOLLOWS` is not part of your example input. Is your input like `STYWXY\nHIM\nsome_line\nABCDEFG\nHIM\n` or like `HIM\nSTYWXY\nsome_random_line\nHIM\nABCDEFG\n`?

Answer (score 1):

This does what you ask. Here's your input text file:

```
$ cat in.txt
STUVWXY

FOLLOWS

HIM

ABCDEFG

FOLLOWS

HIM

IJKLMNO

FOLLOWS

HIM
```

Here's a command line that will result in the desired output.

```
$ grep -v "^$" in.txt | grep -v FOLLOWS | grep -B1 HIM | grep -v HIM
STUVWXY
ABCDEFG
IJKLMNO
```

But this would give you the same output:

```
$ grep -v "^$" in.txt | grep -v FOLLOWS | grep -v HIM
STUVWXY
ABCDEFG
IJKLMNO
```

It is not clear to me what you are asking. I suspect there is something that you still need to articulate in your question.

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk 'r && !/HIM/ && r!="HIM"{ print r }{ r=$0 }' file
```

The output:

```
STUVWXY
ABCDEFG
IJKLMNO
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your requirement is for which line to print but it sounds like it's one of these:

```
$ cat file
STUVWXY
FOLLOWS
HIM
ABCDEFG
FOLLOWS
HIM
IJKLMNO
FOLLOWS
HIM

$ awk '/HIM/{print p} {p=$0}' file
FOLLOWS
FOLLOWS
FOLLOWS

$ awk '/HIM/{print p2} {p2=p; p=$0}' file
STUVWXY
ABCDEFG
IJKLMNO
```